# Input type file click - remove previously added file

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

In javascript I can call add file programmatically:

```
 <input ref="inptFile" type="file" id="selectedFile" name="files" multiple style="display: none;"/>
 <input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
```

When I click first time and I added first file, it's ok, file is added. But when I click second time, the second file is added, but the first file is removed.
How to add second file without removing the first?

I try to write method in typescript to do this programmatically:

```
 addAttachmentClick() {
      document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();

      debugger;
      var addedFile = (<HTMLInputElement>this.$refs.inptFile).files[(<HTMLInputElement>this.$refs.inptFile).files.length - 1];

      this.addFilesToUpload.push({
        name: addedFile.name,
        size: addedFile.size,
        type: addedFile.type,
        lastModifiedDate: addedFile.lastModifiedDate
      });

      this.addedFilesToUpload.push(addedFile);

      for (let addedFileItem in this.addedFilesToUpload) {
        (<HTMLInputElement>this.$refs.inptFile).files.push(addedFileItem);
      }
    },
```

But I got error, because files array don't have push (files.push) method and I don't know how to add the second file to input file (.files) array programmatically.

Comment: This is how it works. You arr using `multiple` attribute to select multiple files all at once. Why do you need to click 2nd time to click other file ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: it could be files in a different folder than the first selection...

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to add multiple files at once and then add several files from different folders